# menu is not showing properly

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I am working on **premiumepress - RealtorPress child theme** and currently having an issue with the menu.

I actually use the PremiumPress PHP code to show the menu

```
<?php echo $ThemeDesign->LAY_NAVIGATION(); ?>
```

I wrap this code under my CSS like:

```
<ul class="sf-menu">
    <?php echo $ThemeDesign->LAY_NAVIGATION(); ?> 
</ul> <!-- END .sf-menu -->
```

I'm using **Superfish** for the menu, but I am unable to understand why its' not working properly as I use this plugin correctly.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
        jQuery('ul.sf-menu').superfish({
            delay:       200, 
            animation:   {opacity:'show',height:'show'},
            speed:       'fast',
            autoArrows:  false,
            dropShadows: false
        });
    });     
</script>
```

But when I see the home page ... I discover there are some irrelevant **div's** inside the menu..

```
<div class="dropdown_1column"> <div class="col_1 firstcolumn">
```

please check the real link to get idea .. what i am talking about :

http://www.ruralpropertyagents.com/

So please help me get rid of this ..

Answer (score 2):

Your hunch is correct - remove those `div` elements and you'll be fixed. I used fiddler to remove them from the markup and it cleared up the issue immediately. They currently wrap all of your nested unordered lists.

When all is corrected, the structure should resemble the following:

```
<ul class="sf-menu">
  <li><a href="...">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="...">Commercial Sales</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="...">Industrial Units for Sale</a></li>
        <li><a href="...">Office Blocks for Sale</a></li>
      </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: mate i know that too ... thats what i talk about. i m asking for the solution .. that how i remove these div's. because they are generating autometically because premiumpress php code .. `<?php echo $ThemeDesign->LAY_NAVIGATION(); ?>`

Comment: @MuzammilHussain You could modify the `$ThemeDesign` class to remove them. Open up the source and find the portion where they're mentioned. You could also just avoid their navigation completely (probably wiser) and create your own in WordPress.

Comment: thats the issue .. i m lookng for the class and unable to find it.

Comment: @MuzammilHussain Look within `/wp-content/themes/[theme name]/`.